# How to set up a remote MariaDB server to work on webphpmyadmin/ampache?

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to setup a remote MariaDB server that I can login to with https://webphpmyadmin.com/index.php. I'm actually using webphpmyadmin to test to see if I can login to my MariaDB server from the web so that I can ultimately use the database for an Ampache web server that I'm trying to setup. Logging into the server on webphpmyadmin seems almost impossible.

I granted the database with privileges with:

```
GRANT ALL ON (database name).\* to '(the username)'@'%' 
IDENTIFIED BY '(the password)' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And I'm able to login to the database with:

```
mysql -u (the username) -h (ip address shown with "ip addr") -p
```

And my firewall with the `sudo ufw status verbose` command shows:

```
Status: active  
Logging: on (low)  
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)  
New profiles: skip

To                       Action      From  
\--                         ------          ----  
3306/tcp             ALLOW IN    Anywhere                     
3306/tcp (v6)      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

But when logging into https://webphpmyadmin.com/index.php, I can't, and I get:

> mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
>
> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

What am I missing? I'm running on Manjaro Linux btw.

Comment: Actually, I realized I was entering the database in the server field when perhaps I should've been entering an ip address. But when I entered my ip address and the username and password, the connection times out. And when I enter webphpmyadmin's ip (212.47.237.65), it says access denied. So I still can't seem to login.

Comment: Are you using a public IP address? Is your attempt at using `mysql` client from outside your network? Is there some other device blocking public access? Is there a reason you trust this website to access your database?

Comment: So after you asked if I used my public IP address, I tried using it. The connection times out. I don't think I'm using the client outside my network, and I don't know if there is a device blocking public access. However, actually I'm considering not using the website and my local database, but instead I want to see if I can use dbninja to set up a remote database. I'm not sure how it'll play out. Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: databases that are network local to the webserver are a good idea. Happy SQLing